# How to select DOM elements from map function in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dictionary, dom

In this simple components I want to select all inputs and listen to a change event, but I got just a  null node list, but me I want the selected inputs.
How I can select inputs inside this map function ?

```
  const Component = () => {

     const [categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
     const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

     const myFun = () => {
        // I want to get all inputs of type cheeckbox;
        const inps = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
        console.log(inps); // but I get nodeList[]
    }

    useEffect(() => {
       setCategories([...Fetched Categories from the server])
       setLoading(true);
       myFunc();
   }, []);
 return <div id="component"> 
        { loading && (categories.map((c,i)=>(
           <div className="form-group" key={i}>
             <label htmlFor={c.id}>
                <input type="checkbox" value={c.id} id={c.id}  />
                {c.title}
             </label>
           </div>
         )))
       }
     </div>
 }
export default Component;
```

Comment: Do you need to observe change events from useEffect for some reason? It seems it would be more straightforward to add an onChange handler directly to your input elements.

Comment: Yes, using an `onChange` handler and appropriate state update is the react way.

Comment: thank you so much, I was need to listen changes on my elements to do other things, so onChange it works with me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no inputs when you call myFunc(). Your setLoading(true) will affect html only on next render.
The best way to access dom nodes in react is to use thise hook https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref